# PowerShell, formatting large XML result from SQL

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that executes a stored procedure in SQL, which returns a large, single, XML result. I need to save this XML result to a file.

Unfortunately, the output gets marred by PowerShell trying to make things look pretty.

```
 $xmldataset.tables[0] | ft -wrap -hidetableheaders | out-file C:\xml_result.xml
```

That will get me the full result, but it wraps the result where it would as if it were displaying it on my screen. This will break most XML parsers.

```
$xmldataset.tables[0] | ft -hidetableheaders | out-file C:\xml_result.xml
```

That just arbitrarily breaks my result into two lines, truncating each line.

It appears unless I use the -wrap, it's putting the result into two rows, even though it is just one row being returned from SQL.

Here is the full code

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.sp_getXML"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SqlServer; Database = $SqlCatalog; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$xmlDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($xmlDataSet)
```

How can I just get the output from SQL saved to a file, preferrably saving the linebreaks created by the SQL result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the formatting like this:

```
$xmldataset.tables[0] | ft -wrap -hidetableheaders | out-string | out-file C:\xml_result.xml
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still adds linebreaks. It seems to be adding them where it would normally add them if it were displaying the result in the console (i.e. it changes according to window size).

Comment: That's what format-table does. If you just want the output save to a file, pipe it directly to set-content, without the ft in between.

Comment: I was doing format-table because otherwise it's including the header and breaks the data result onto two rows.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the table header and elipsis (...) truncation. I found this article http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2008/12/09/powershell-output-capturing-and-text-wrapping-strange-quirks-solved.aspx which is starting to make me think powershell is not the best solution for me.

Comment: You need to avoid the format-* cmdlets, and just output the row value to the row/column value to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working best for me.

```
$xml = ""
for ($i=0; $i -lt $xmldataset.tables[0].rows.count; $i++){
    $xml = $xml+$xmldataset.tables[0].rows[$i][0].ToString()
}
$xml | out-file -filepath C:\Users\mvrydaghs\Documents\test_copy\xml_result.xml
```

Since it's randomly breaking the result into multiple rows, I needed the loop. Writing directly to the file in the loop still introduced unwanted and unasked for linebreaks, so I had to use an additional variable for concatination and then write that to the file.